# Bootstrap tooltips don't work in page different from the first of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, tooltip

I'm developing several datatables where the cells of some columns have bootstrap tooltips.
So i'm using:

- Bootstrap framework
- [Datatables](http://datatables.net/).

The Datatables is organized in several pages.
When the document is ready and the table is loaded, in the first page of the datatables the tooltips are working fine, but the cells of the nexts pages have no tooltips!

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You need to use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to initialize tooltips every time DataTables redraws the table. This is needed because `TR` and `TD` elements for pages other than first are not present in DOM at the time first page is displayed.

#### DEMO

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {     
        ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
        drawCallback: function(settings){
            var api = this.api();
            
            /* Add some tooltips for demonstration purposes */
            $('td', api.table().container()).each(function () {
               $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
            });

            /* Apply the tooltips */
            $('td', api.table().container()).tooltip({
               container: 'body'
            });          
        }  
    }); 
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>      
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, it solved perfectly my problem.

Comment: @Gyrocode thanks for the solution, i was about to write custom tooltip then found this :):)

Comment: Using the `api` like this, how can I add tooltips to a specific column? In this example, only on `Position` I want the hover text.